# Connecting Oracle Database to Windows application C#

Tags: c#, oracle

ultimate beginner here in C#. Here is the big picture background: This application will take a scanned barcode into a textbox, I presume, and just compare database value from 1 table to see if anything matches it. If not, then an error will display. If it does the user will then continue to fill in information into the ERP system.

Currently, I'm just trying to connect my application to the database and am getting nowhere. We use Oracle.

Here is my code that doesn't work so far:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
{
    {
    public void CreateOracleConnection()
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=Oracle8i;Integrated Security=yes";
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("ServerVersion: " + connection.ServerVersion
                + "\nDataSource: " + connection.DataSource);
        }
    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

There is probably a lot wrong going on here but if someone can just nudge me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. As each time I find sample code it's pretty old and obsolete. I've also read about needing references for the Oracle database and have no idea about any of that either.

So thanks for helping out a severely lost newbie.

edit: As stated below I didn't actually specifiy what *isn't* working for me. What isn't working seems to be the actual database connection it seems. I keep getting an error that states:

"The type or namespace name 'OracleConnection' could not be found(are you missing using a directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: "Here is my code that doesn't work so far:" - please explain what 'doesn't work' means.....

Comment: Ah. My apologies. What isn't working seems to be the actual database connection it seems. I keep getting an error that states: "The type or namespace name 'OracleConnection' could not be found(are you missing using a directive or an assembly reference?)" 

I am also pretty big newbie at understanding what exactly isn't working as well.

Comment: At a minimum, the OracleConnection is part of a specific library for connectivity from .NET applications back to Oracle databases. Microsoft used to provide one that is long-since deprecated; otherwise, you'll need to have the relevant drivers from Oracle installed on your box. If they already are, you need to add a "Reference" to what is most likely the Oracle.DataAccess assembly within your app  and add a proper "using..." reference in your source.....and that's likely just the beginning :)

Comment: If your using Oracle 8i, you need to check which drivers will connect.  I'm not sure if the newer drivers will connect to that version of the server.  You probably have to find the ODAC driver that connects, The somewhat newer version uses Oracle.DataAcess.Client.  A sample connection string (in the web/app.config) for this would be: connectionString="Data Source=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>  You have to lookup whether Oracle can use the integrated security (your NTLM credentials).

Comment: Thanks. This will give me enough information to trudge through and figure out the rest.

Comment: Any update on figuring this out?  Eventually you will want to use a 3rd party library to connect to an Oracle DB (probably from Oracle) since the ones provided by the .NET framework are deprecated.

Comment: Yes, an update! A good one at that. By scouring around some more I came upon the fact that I did not have the necessary ODP.Net resource. I was also trying to set up the database connection the wrong way entirely, going through Data Source and not Server Explorer. Once I installed what was necessary it was all a breeze from there.

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like you are missing your "using" in front of
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection
2. In your using, you need to use the namespace "System.Data.OracleClient", you don't use the last part, OracleConnection, as it is not a namespace but a class included in the OracleClient namespace.
3. To import a reference, in VisualStudio, right click on References in the Solution Explorer, and click on "Add Reference".  Then in the search box, type "oracle" and you should see "System.Data.OracleClient" show up.  Check it off and press OK.  You will now see it listed under the References section.

Comment: As an FYI, System.Data.OracleClient (Microsoft) was deprecated some time ago.  There have been at least two versions of the ODP/ODAC (Oracle Data Provider / Oracle Data Access Components) since then, and the "using" is slightly different depending on which version your using.

Comment: This is true, but going by op's example, was just trying to help him to get his his program to run.  What I said will work _(for the time being)_ but like you said, it will give you the warning that it is obsolete, which should hint as to why he came across all of the old/obsolete posts.